# Updating Custom Fields From Mysql To Quickbooks Desktop Using PHP Web Connector

Tags: php, quickbooks

I have a web app (running locally - in apache localhost) in which I add new students. I then populate Quickbooks with that data from the database (after creating a new student). The problem I have is with custom fields that the students table has. I created those fields manually in Quickbooks but when I create a new student, those custom fields don't get filled with data. There are no errors so I can't really determine what's wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

The attached pictures shows my custom fields in Quickbooks

[image]

Here is the code snippet that I use to add new student request from the server in to Quickbooks Desktop

The code that queues up requests to Web connector

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "academy";

// Create connection
// $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

$dsn02 = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname;
$handler = new PDO( $dsn02, $user, $password );

/**
 * Require some configuration stuff
 */ 
require_once '../motionplus/app_web_connector/config.php';

$sql = "INSERT INTO students (firstname,level,registration_number)
VALUES(?, ?, ?);";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO bills_module (firstname,level,registration_number)
VALUES(?, ?, ?);";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO bills (firstname,level,registration_number)
VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

$pdo = $handler -> prepare($sql);

if ($pdo -> execute([
    $_POST['firstname'], 
    $_POST['level'], 
    $_POST['registration_number'], 
    $_POST['firstname'], 
    $_POST['level'], 
    $_POST['registration_number'], 
    $_POST['firstname'], 
    $_POST['level'], 
    $_POST['registration_number']
    ])
) {
    // Get the primary key of the new record
    $id = $handler -> lastInsertId();

    // Queue up the customer add 
    $Queue = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue($dsn);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, $id);

    echo "<center>New record created successfully</center>";

    header("Location:fees_capture.php");

    echo "<center><a href='fees_capture.php'>View Registered Students</a></center>";
} else {
    echo "Some serious error happened. Run!";
}
```

The code that adds students to quickbooks

```
function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{

// Fetch student record from the database
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'academy';
$user = 'root';
$secret = '';

$dsn01 = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname;
$handler = new PDO( $dsn01, $user, $secret );

$pdo = $handler -> prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = ?");

$pdo -> execute([$ID]);

$record = $pdo -> fetch(5);

// Create and return a qbXML request
$qbxml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
            <CustomerAdd>
                <Name>' . $record -> firstname . '</Name>
                <CompanyName>The Lilongwe Academy</CompanyName>
                <FirstName>' . $record -> firstname . '</FirstName>
                <LastName>' . $record -> lastname . '</LastName>
            </CustomerAdd>
        </CustomerAddRq>

        <DataExtModRq>
            <DataExtMod>
                <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                <DataExtName>Registration Number</DataExtName>
                <ListDataExtType>Customer</ListDataExtType>
                <ListObjRef>
                    <FullName>Kingsley Nyirenda</FullName>
                </ListObjRef>
                    <DataExtValue>' . $record -> registration_number . '</DataExtValue>
            </DataExtMod>
        </DataExtModRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>';

return $qbxml;
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual qbXML request you sent to QuickBooks, AND the qbXML response you got BACK from QuickBooks. Also, posting the rest of your code may be helpful. You might find this information in either the quickbooks_log SQL table, or the Web Connector log file.

Comment: I don't know where I can find those logs. I found the QCWLog.txt file and the log in there is as below:

Comment: Then you should post the rest of your code, so we can provide better info for you.

Comment: @keith_palmer_jr I have updated the question and included all the code I used.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your code is trying to fill a custom field named `Classs`, which your screenshot indicates you *do not have in QuickBooks*.

> DataExtName=Classs

2. Your code has a gigantic security vulnerability because you're not escaping your inputs or using prepared statements:

> $sql = "INSERT INTO students (firstname,level,registration_number)
>               VALUES('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[level]','$_POST[registration_number]');";
>
> $sql .= "INSERT INTO bills_module (firstname,registration_number,level)
>               VALUES('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[registration_number]','$_POST[level]');";
>
> $sql .= "INSERT INTO bills (firstname,registration_number,level)
>               VALUES('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[registration_number]','$_POST[level]')";

Comment: I have updated the code to pdo with prepared statements

Comment: @keith_palmer_jr Having corrected the errors you pointed out, still more the custom fields are not being populated with data (in this case, the Registration Number field).

Comment: And yet, you STILL haven't posted your logs, so we're unable to help you.

Comment: Those (in VERBOSE mode) and the logs from the `quickbooks_log` SQL table would be helpful.  You should be able to find the exact qbXML request sent to QuickBooks, and the qbXML response (complete with error message).

Comment: @keith_palmer_jr I have found 3 quickbooks_log (namely .myd .myi and .frm). I have noticed that the quickbooks_log.myd is more readable so I'll just send that here

Comment: @keith_palmer_jr I took a peek at the logs and I saw from the response request that the <ListObjejRef><FullName>Kingsley</FullName></ListObjRef> does not exist in the list... The error says "Invalid argument. The specified record does not exist in the list."

Comment: @keith_palmer_jr I am unable to include the log file here...but I'll just write the sent request and the response manually. Then I'll write the error that is shown in the log

Comment: Do you know what an SQL query is? You don't have phpMyAdmin or access to the MySQL console, so you can run an SQL query against the `quickbooks_log` SQL table? In any case, it sounds like your customer does not exist. Create the customer first before you add the custom fields.